# How to write an huge bytearray to file progressively without hitting MemoryError

Tags: python, arrays

I am working on a tool that generates random data for testing purposes. See below the part of my code that is giving me grief. This works perfectly and faster(takes around 20 seconds) than conventional solutions when the file is around 400MB, however, once it reaches around 500MB I am getting an out of memory error. How can I pull contents from the memory and write it in a file progressively  having not more than 10 MB in my memory at a single time.

```
def createfile(filename,size_kb):
    tbl = bytearray(range(256))
    numrand = os.urandom(size_kb*1024)
    with open(filename,"wb") as fh:
    fh.write(numrand.translate(tbl))

createfile("file1.txt",500*1024)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the purpose of the `translate()`? In this code it translates each byte onto itself, achieving nothing. As for how to use less memory, simply grab the random bytes in chunks.... say 1MB or something and iterate until the required amount of bytes is fulfulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comibining Jaco and mhawk and handling some float conversions.. here is the code that can generate Gbs of data in less than 10 seconds

```
def createfile(filename,size_kb):
    chunksize = 1024
    chunks = math.ceil(size_kb / chunksize)
    with open(filename,"wb") as fh:
        for iter in range(chunks):
            numrand = os.urandom(int(size_kb*1024 / chunks))
            fh.write(numrand)
        numrand = os.urandom(int(size_kb*1024 % chunks))
        fh.write(numrand)
```

Creates 1 Gb file in less than 8 seconds

Answer (score 2):

You can write out chunks of 10MB at a time, rather than generating the entire file in one go. As pointed out by @mhawke,  the `translate` call is redundant and can be removed:

```
def createfile(filename,size_kb):
    chunks = size_kb /(1024*10)
    with open(filename,"wb") as fh:
        for iter in range(chunks):
            numrand = os.urandom(size_kb*1024 / chunks)
            fh.write(numrand)        
        numrand = os.urandom(size_kb*1024 % chunks)    
        fh.write(numrand)

createfile("c:/file1.txt",500*1024)
```

Comment: `chunksize = 1024; chunks = math.ceil(size_kb / chunksize)`  as urandom expects an integer

Comment: This is only required if size_kb is a `float1, otherwise python will perform an integer division. The remainder is handled by the second numrand instance